# Getting PHP working with MS Sql on Windows with VS2022 and IIS Express

Tags: php, sql-server, visual-studio-2022, iis-express

I am trying to get a simple and sample database query working from a webpage in Visual Studio 2022 with PHP Tools for Visual Studio 2022 from DEVSENSE with IIS Express and VS 2022 debug.
I know the base PHP install is working because I can run a script

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

And get the report dumped to a web page.
However, I can’t seem to get the PDO driver for MS SQL to load DLL and show up in the report.

I have added and modified the appropriate lines in php.ini file located in C:\Program Files\IIS Express\PHP\v8.2\ext
Have retried restarting VS so that IIS Express gets restarted,

```
\[ExtensionList\]
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dllextension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll
```

Results from phpinfo();

```
PHP Version 8.2.1
System  Windows NT JEFFMU-XPS13-32 10.0 build 22621 (Windows 11) AMD64
Build Date  Jan 3 2023 23:31:42
Build System    Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter \[10.0.17763\]
Compiler    Visual C++ 2019
Architecture    x64
Configure Command   cscript /nologo /e:jscript configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--with-pdo-oci=........\\instantclient\\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-19=........\\instantclient\\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Server API  Built-in HTTP server
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   no value
Loaded Configuration File   C:\\Program Files\\IIS Express\\PHP\\v8.2\\php.ini

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which article you followed to perform the setup, but it is wrong to use `php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_*.dll`.

PHP 8.2 requires up-to-date SQL Server driver files from [Microsoft GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases). And right now you can only download "Windows-8.2.zip" from 5.11.0 as it added PHP 8.2 support. All previous releases do not support PHP 8.2.

The files from the ZIP package are `php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_*.dll` for your reference.

## Reference

- https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.11.0
- https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1420

Comment: Changing it to drivers you referenced did not resolve it loading the ms sql drivers for PDO.

Comment: @JeffMuzzy you should update the question itself and include the latest information.

Comment: Microsoft has just officially released its Sql driver 5.11 for PHP 8.2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server

Comment: @b126 Thanks. Revised the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are new drivers out for PHP 8.3.

https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.12.0-beta1